# Laplace transformations of dependent sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform, nodal-analysis

The following example is from the book *Fundamentals of electric circuits* by Charles K. Alexander. I don't understand how the dependent current source of 2δ(t) in the question becomes a 2 A current source. What I've learned is that 2f(t) is 2F(s) when transformed.

[image]

Comment: What is the Laplace transform of [\$\delta(t)\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)? (don't miss the link)

Answer (score 0):

That source is actually not a dependent source (denoted as it is shown as a circle, not a diamond in the diagram). That symbol is the dirac delta impulse symbol which signifies an instantaneous pulse of current (which immediately turns off at t=0+). The laplace transform of the dirac function is 1. Thus, the laplace transform of the current source is 2. Hope this helps.